# How to simulate click to specific background window (not in focus)?

Tags: python, autohotkey

I am trying to click a window that is in the background (without focus), without moving the mouse cursor (so I can continue to use my screen and mouse normally).

Using Python win32gui the application isn't registering the click. Using AutoHotkey I couldn't find a way to simulate the click (I only managed to write to it because I didn't find anything like `win.click` or `ahk.controlclick`). Can I do it with AutoHotkey or is there anything else I can use?

The code which doesn't work:

```
def click(x, y):
    hWnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "Spotify")
    lParam = win32api.MAKELONG(x, y)

    hWnd1= win32gui.FindWindowEx(hWnd, None, None, None)
    win32gui.SendMessage(hWnd1, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, lParam)
    win32gui.SendMessage(hWnd1, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, None, lParam)
```

Answer (score -1):

A trivial approach that is not very robust, is using `PyAutoGUI`
you just need to

1. install it using `pip install pyautogui` or if you are using `poetry`, you can install by using the following command `poetry add pyautogui`
2. then use the function `pyautogui.click(x, y)` and pass `int` values to them
3. you can also move the cursor to `pyautogui.moveTo(x,y)` absolute movement or you can move it relative to the current cursor position by using `pyautogui.move(x, y)`

A more robust approach is to use an image of where you want to move the mouse and use `pyautogui.locateOnScreen('path_to_image')`

Comment: Yes my program is using pyautogui but the problem is that it is moving my mouse so I cant work on the computer while it is running. I'm  trying to just simulate the click without my mouse being moved by the program and the program where the click is simulated could be behind some apps that I'm using

Comment: The answer is you can't do it. Not with those tools.  Best you can hope for is to wait for some idle time from mouse and keyboard events and as quickly as you can, save mouse position, grab focus on the target app (no need to bring it forward, just keep in background but make active), simulate the mouse click at the position, and return focus and mouse position to the original app you were in.  You might be able to cleverly capture any mouse keyboard activity during this and "replay" them once focus is restored, too.  The point is, mouse and key can only be used with the thing that is active.